Cap Array Modifier over a curve modifier not create volume (3dprint)
I have a "DEM" (Digital Elevation Model) mesh, and a section type to cut the dem, follow a curve center line below the dem at desired depth (this is a for a hydrologic work) 
To create the cut I tried this procedure:

import the section that I created in assets
move to snap the section at the first point of the curve centerline
parent the section over the curve, so I can move the curve at desired depth
create the caps of the section (the section is a triangle without the section faces along z axe). the two cap objects are the two faces along z axe.
modifier curve to adjust the direction of the section
modifier array to follow the curve (relative offset)
selection of the two cap objects in the specific part of the array modifier, to create a volume
boolean intersect object developed section along the curve, with the dem

It seems "caps" doesn't create a volume!

If I apply without cap and create the "caps" after (with fill) all go well!

But I must use modifier because it's necessary have the possibility to change curve center line or some dimension of the section to correct the "cut"
Is there the possibilities to create a volume of an array?

What do you mean by "DEM" mesh ? Screenshots and your blend file would help a lot : I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about, and thus can't help.

excuse me. DEM Digital Elevation Model. Screenshots added

It's easier if you:

keep your section on the XY plane (centered at 0,0).
use the "geometry > object -> bevel" property of the curve path to create the volume
and finally convert curve to mesh


Converting mesh to curve or the other way around:

The section
Create a mesh circle, edit as you like, convert it to a curve.
Keep it on the XY plane, centered at 0,0

The path "extrusion"
Create a curve path, go to the curve properties and add the section as the object for the "geometry -> object -> bevel".
(One thing that might bother you is the orientation of each point on the curve, in edit mode, press N for a selected vertex and control its tilt accordingly)

And convert this to mesh, you will be able to use it as a boolen object.
After having it as a mesh, you can do a boolean difference

(The little flaw on top of the hill was my bad, converted the curve to mesh before making it the right size)

Thank you Daniel. In my try your procedure: the orientation result was not exact. The tilt of every vertices of the curve was 0. But very good: I studied only the mesh tools, and I don't know the possibilities of the curve.

Yeah, I had the same orientation problem... fixed it fine tuning the orientation of each point.

It's very simple: only create the "circle" in x-y axis, and you don't rotate, that it was my mistake.

Thank you Daniel again. Rethinking about your procedure, it's not that I'm looking for, because it's necessary to calculate volume of the results changing depth and position of the fill section. So a parametric possibility, with geometry nodes. And it seems to me difficult use to start a curve object. (but I'm novice with Blender)

I'm able to calculate the volume with only modifier adding a remesh modifier (with voxel): maybe some simplification, but it works), before boolean

Bro... you gotta ask what you want to ask
